# Snap applications unable to connect to the internet if VPN is turned on?

Tags: networking, internet, vpn, snap

I use ExpressVPN to keep my internet browsing private in public places. Whenever I am connected to any VPN server, Snap apps such as Discord and Spotify are unable to connect to the internet.

I have looked in the permissions section in the software store, but changing these around did not affect this issue. I am currently using Discord and Spotify in the browser, and I would like my Snaps to work.

What can I do?

Comment: What happens if you connect tp VPN first, then start applications?

Comment: same issue, they are unable to connect

Answer (score 0):

same issue. As for Spotify do this -> https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Spotify-error-code-4-with-ExpressVPN-on-Ubuntu-18-04/td-p/4503841

1. `$ sudo snap remove spotify`
2. `$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0DF731E45CE24F27EEEB1450EFDC8610341D9410`
3. `$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"`
4. `sudo apt install spotify-client`

As for the other apps I'm wondering myself. Telegram works but a few others don't. I spoke with ExpressVPN support but it led nowhere.

Comment: Im not sure what you changed. Side-by-side shows no difference.